# junit Assert Equals

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit

Problem: When doing the comparison, I get a fail trace error, but the expected and actual result is the same. I first get the output of the string, copied that from the console that is returned in eclipse, and used that string as the exact comparison. Is there an issue when there are new lines involved?

```
@Test
public void testErrorPage() throws InterruptedException{
    // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\HASANK\\Desktop\\tEST\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); 
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("http://thisisatest.com");
    Thread.sleep(3500);  // Let the user actually see something!

    String  error= driver.findElement(By.className("errorText")).getText();;
    System.out.println(error);

    String expectedTitle = "404\r\n" + 
            "The requested URL was not found on this server.";
  assertEquals(expectedTitle,error);
  driver.quit();
}
```

String that is returned from the gettext:

> 404
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: Hope you had fun ha. Did you end up going to the aquarium/seaport? Sidenote: I ended up using: assertThat(text, containsString("404"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is here: `"404\r\n"`: it is simply pretty *easy* to get such line break things **wrong**.

So the real answer is to **avoid** doing such *exact* equality comparisons. Instead, you could be doing

```
assertThat(actual, contains("whatever"))
```

where `contains()` would be a hamcrest matcher, that checks if "whatever" shows up *somewhere* in `actual`.

Of course, the downside of `contains()` is that it might lead to "false positives" when the string to match is "too generic". But on the other hand: `contains()` is also much more robust against changes. When you do *exact* matching, a tab-turned-into-a-space here, or an additional space/newline there breaks your *exact* match. And especially when testing "web output", you need to be **robust**. Otherwise you keep constantly updating your test cases because of subtle changes in the output.

Comment: This method works- thanks for the help and clarification!

Comment: There is a danger in using `contains()` though in that if you look for too small a string, you could get matches where you aren't expecting them and get a false positive. You also aren't checking the entire message. What if the error message got munged and returned 10 `\r\n`s instead of 1? I personally would take the 60s needed to get the exact string using the dev console in the browser... but that would depend on what exactly you are trying to verify and would vary from test to test.

Comment: Sure. But *exact* messages are subject to change. But I will add a bit to my answer, so thanks @JeffC 1